# leer un archivo .json en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola necesito leer un archivo json en angular mediante un servicio, utilizando el servico http

```
app.factory('Expenses', function($http){
var service = {};

service.entries = [];

$http.get('data/get_all.json').then(function (data){
        service.entries = data;

        //convertir fecha de string a objeto
        service.entries.forEach(function(element){
            element.date = myHelpers.stringToDateObj(element.date);
        });
    }).catch(function(data, status){
    alert('error no se puede leer el archivo!');
    });
```

Estoy utilizando angular 1.6.7
y cambie el archivo angular.min.js ---> angular 1.5.9
para hacer pruebas.

Ayuda, no me lee el archivo, me manda la alert.

tenia success y lo cambie por then, cambie error por catch

Comment: Puedes imprimir el error que lanza y agregarlo a tu pregunta?

Comment: Listo ya puse la imagen del error.

Comment: Esos no son los errores relacionados a tu archivo angular, son errores de sass. A la derecha puedes ver el nombre de archivo, linea y columna que lanzó el error. Debería ser algo como nombre.js

Comment: Editare de nuevo la pregunta.

Comment: Digo que hagas esto: .catch(function(err){console.log(err);})  en lugar de .catch(function(data,status){alert("cadena");}). De lo contrario no podras ver el error

Comment: ya lo hice pero no me muestra errores ni me muestra los datos del archivo .json

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73086/discussion-between-absalon-castanon-and-estefania).

Comment: ¿Estás interesada en seguir con la resolución de este problema? Con el tiempo que ha pasado es posible que lo hayas solucionado. Podría ayudarte si aún necesitas ayuda.

Comment: Al ingresar a la url del json en tu navegador muestra el JSON?

Comment: AngularJS. Otro framework más del montón. No hay nada mejor que usar un "lenguaje de programación", no una "simple implementación". Otra de las muchas desventajas de los frameworks: pueden quedar obsoletos en cuestión de pocos años. Basta con que aparezca un nuevo framework, se haga popular y reemplace poco a poco a los que eran populares hasta ese momento. Con los verdaderos lenguajes no ocurre eso. Sino pregúntenle a Java, C++ o Python, que llevan más de 30 años en el ciberespacio y parecen que nunca envejecen. Sobretodo Python, cuya popularidad crece por montones. ¡Gracias Guido van Rossun!

Answer (score 0):

Si observas el código que recibe el navegador notarás que no se han reflejado los cambios que mencionaste(success por then).
El error que surge es que la función success no esta definida.
Seguramente esto sucede porque el navegador tiene el código de app.js en caché. Lo que puedes hacer para evitar eso es, en el atributo src de la etiqueta script agregar un parámetro a la url, por ejemplo

```
 src="./app.js?x=7"
```

Si estarás editando app.js frecuentemente podrías generar un valor aleatorio para el parámetro de la url, de esta forma el navegador no se dará cuenta de que es la misma url  y cargara el archivo modificado cada vez que recargues la pagina

Comment: Ya lo hice pero no me marca ningùn error. y no me muestra los datos del archivo json.

Comment: Pero ya no muestra el error en consola(success is not a function) cierto?